# iOS: Using auto resize mask to keep UIView at bottom of phone, no matter the screen size

Tags: ios, autoresizingmask

[image: http://note.io/14639No]

I've attached a screenshot of a color view I would like to have positioned at the bottom of the screen using the auto resize mask.

I've tried every combination of resize masks I can think of, but when I change the simulated metric's Size to 3.5 or 4 inch, it doesn't move. :(

What am I doing wrong? Is this possible with auto resizing masks?

[image]

*Edit*
Attached an image with me anchoring to bottom as well.

Comment: You have it attached to the top, not the bottom in the image you show in your link.

Comment: Added image with bottom attachment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you probably want is something like:

[image]

The fixed i-beam (the vertical "strut") at the bottom says "keep my distance to the bottom constant" (i.e. stay pegged at the bottom). The lack of the up-down arrow (the "spring") says "don't change my height as my superview's height changes."

The other three, horizontal components are optional: the left and right i-beams (struts) say "if I go between landscape and portrait, keep the left and right distances pegged where they are" and the left and right arrow in the middle (the spring) says "and let this change the width as the superview gets wider or narrower."

This will fix the 3.5" vs 4.0" problem. It should also handle different widths as well (e.g. landscape or if you ever use this scene as subview in custom container or if Apple ever releases larger screen devices), should you ever need that.

---

In your revised question, you say that that when you used this autosizing setting, it didn't fix the problem until you rebuilt the scene from scratch, at which point using this autosizing setting did fix it. The likely problem in that original scene was probably, as VinceBurn points out, that in addition to the above autosizing settings, one of the superviews of this bottom view was probably not, itself, autosizing correctly. One always has to consider not only the current view's autosizing settings, but also all of the views in the view hierarchy.

Comment: I could have sworn I've tried setting the bottom strut (by itself and along with all the other combinations, nothing seems to make a difference.) Is there a setting somewhere I may missed? I have "auto resize subviews" checked on the parent view.

Comment: @bobber205 is your view on the top level view, or do you have some other intermediary view? Just the two views (top-level and this little view), or anything else there? Look at the document outline panel on the left and make sure you don't have any extraneous views.

Comment: It's a view -> then this purple view in the screenshot.

Comment: I also have a small similar view at the "top" of the screen

Comment: @bobber205 When you select the scene itself, and look at "simulated metrics", does "size" say "inferred"? When you click on the 3.5" vs 4.0" button, does the view itself change size? And you're saying that your little purple view disappears at 3.5", but is visible at 4.0"?

Comment: The purple view is "below" the bottom of the screen (or at least it seems so) in 3.5 and visible in 4.0. When I initially placed it with the "Inferred" size, I put it at the bottom.

Comment: @bobber205 We're reaching the point of diminishing returns trying to diagnose this via comments. You might just want to share the project (remove anything proprietary, as needed) with us so we can take a look. Also, you might want to create a new blank project, add this purple view, and see if setting the strings and struts outlined above fixes it or not. That way you can diagnose whether it's something about your existing project or not.

Comment: Remaking the view with a fresh view controller seemed to have fixed all my problems. I know it makes this whole quesiton useless but at least it's something to try!

Comment: The above is what I ultimately needed to do in a new view. So accepting this as the answer.

Comment: @Rob having both left and right struts means there must be a horizontal spring, right ?

Comment: @entropy Yes, if you turn on the left and right struts (effectively saying "keep the left and right margins fixed"), then it only makes sense to do that if you also turn on the horizontal width spring (e.g. "let the width autosize").

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried every combination of resize masks I can think of, but when I change the simulated metric's Size to 3.5 or 4 inch, it doesn't move. :(

That would suggest that the `superView` of that view doesn't have it's autoresizingMask set to FlexibleHeight (the up/down arrow in Interface Builder).  If the `superView` don't resize your view won't change position.

Comment: oh snap. that's probably it. I'll have to wait until I get into the office tomorrow to try, but I'll be sure to let you know :D

Comment: I'm not able to select the containing view and hit that arrow. I can only select the margins. :(

Answer (score 1):

try setting the auto resizing in the following manner. 
select the bottom view.

[image]

also remove auto layout if you are using. (uncheck auto layout from the File Inspector)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to check the left and right i-beams, and not check the center horizontal width arrow, too (this effectively says "keep left and right margins fixed, but don't change the width"). Also, it doesn't make sense to leave all of the vertical settings selected, too; given that he wanted this pinned to the bottom, he should select the bottom i-beam.

Answer (score 0):

Please check, you have tick out (by mistake, (by default it is ticked)) the `Autoresizesubviews` or not?

If `Autoresize` of the parent view is Off, then autoresize will not work.

Please check below image

[image]